# Is there any Hadith that indicates that preventing someone from going to the mesjid is haram?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

There are many Muslim parents (may Allah guide them) who don't let their sons go to the mesjid for Fajr salah. However, is there any Hadith that forbids preventing the Slaves of Allah from going to the mesjid?

Jazakum Allah khayran,

Comment: This sounds weird and IMO needs some elaboration. There are even ahadith that show it is not allowed to prevent anybody be it male or female to go to any mosque (there are limited exceptions) so why should there be a special ruling with al-Masjid al-Haraam? Please consider explaining what lead you to this question?

Comment: Akhi it's because of the overwhelming amount of Muslim parents who don't let their children go to the mesjid at Fajr.

Comment: There might be many good reasons to prevent them and many not to do so. In this case the parents are responsible and they should know best. Also the age of the children may play a crucial role here. Please add all necessary information in your post I know many stackexchange sites with a more active community where this post would have already been closed due to this lack of information.

Comment: Beside this there are many people who are disliked if not hindered from entering a mosque due to reasons like bad odor or illness and contamination.

Comment: They can just pray on a different side? like some rows behind the people depending on the illness.

Answer (score 1):

Ibn Umar reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Do not prevent women from their share of the mosques, if they seek your permission.”

In another narration, the Prophet said, “Allow women to go to the mosques at night.”

Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 858, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 442

Grade: Muttafaqun Alayhi (authenticity agreed upon) according to Al-Bukhari and Muslim

عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ لَا تَمْنَعُوا النِّسَاءَ حُظُوظَهُنَّ مِنْ الْمَسَاجِدِ إِذَا اسْتَأْذَنُوكُمْ

وفي رواية أخرى قال ائْذَنُوا لِلنِّسَاءِ بِاللَّيْلِ إِلَى الْمَسَاجِدِ

858 صحيح البخاري كتاب الجمعة باب هل على من لم يشهد الجمعة غسل من النساء والصبيان وغيرهم

442 صحيح مسلم كتاب الصلاة باب خروج النساء إلى المساجد إذا لم يترتب عليه فتنة وأنها لا تخرج مطيبة

Source: https://abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2011/07/15/do-not-prevent-women-from-mosque/

Comment: I'm afraid if we take the clarification made by OP into account your answer somewhat missed the topic.